# How to trace enum type in a .vcd file using SystemC AMS?

Tags: systemc

I need to trace enum signals type in SystemC AMS.

This is my code:

```
sca_util::sca_trace_file* atf = sca_util::sca_create_vcd_trace_file( "trace.vcd" );
sca_util::sca_trace( atf, system.cmd_sig_tdf_fw, "controller_cmd" );
```

where "system.cmd_sig_tdf_fw" is a:

```
sca_tdf::sca_signal< command_type > cmd_sig_tdf_fw;
```

And the enum is:

```
enum command_type { IDLE, OPEN, CLOSE };
```

I'm able to trace all tdf double type signal, but command type signal is never traced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum VCD tracing is not supported and is deprecated.
You can find relevant discussion [here](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1309-enumeration-tracing/).

Also I have tried to add enum variables to VCD traces and have observed only constant values being recorded in the VCD trace file.